# How to temporarily modify the CSS of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am adding a CSS rule to an element with jQuery. E.g. `$('#any-el').css('outline', '1px solid red')`.

I later remove the style with `$('#any-el').css('outline', '')`.

I don't want to disturb any other styles this element may have, and I've found that this method works well for CSS added with external or inline stylesheets, but it will (obviously) modify and then remove any 'outline' given added via JavaScript at any previous point.

What is the best way to ensure that the value of the 'outline' style attribute is restored to the way it was before I modified it?

Here is the whole relevant part of the code:

```
   var last_el = null
   $('#mask').mousemove(function(e) {
     var mask = $(this).detach()
     var el = window.document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)
     if (el != last_el) {
       if (last_el) {
         $(last_el).css('outline', '')
       }
       if (el) {
         $(el).css('outline', '1px solid red')
       }
       last_el = el
     }
     $('body').append(mask)
   })
```

(Basically the `#mask` overlays the whole page and I outline the element which the mouse is hovering over, underneath the mask.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you could do to add styles and restore them without any disturbance would be to **put your new styles in a class** and add/remove that class rather than setting inline styles. Make sure that all styles within the class are made [**`!important`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#How_!important_can_be_used).

```js
var $span = $('span');

$('button').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      override = $this.text() === 'Override';
  
  $span.toggleClass('outline-override');
  $this.text(override? 'Restore' : 'Override');
});
```

```css
.outline-override {
    outline: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="outline: 1px solid black;">test</span>

<button>Override</button>
```

Comment: Will this work if there's already an outline style on the DOM object (which is what the OP is asking about)?

Comment: @jfriend00 It would if `!important` is used for every rules, unless `!important` is already used on the inline style.

Comment: Then, you should add that to your answer because it would be a required part of the solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 Added more info and a snippet.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the value of the previous `outline` style in a variable before changing it, and then later restore the value of the variable. E.g.

```
   var last_el = null;
   var outline_style = null;
   $('#mask').mousemove(function(e) {
     var mask = $(this).detach();
     var el = window.document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
     if (el != last_el) {
       if (last_el) {
         $(last_el).css('outline', outline_style);
       }
       if (el) {
         outline_style = $(el).css('outline');
         $(el).css('outline', '1px solid red');
       }
       last_el = el;
     }
     $('body').append(mask);
   });
```

Comment: That works if the styles were inline, but if they were computed from stylesheets it won't.

Comment: That's true, your answer is likely a better solution than mine.

Comment: Well, you could work out something with `getComputedStyles`, but you also need to make sure that you avoid polluting the element inline styles if they came from stylesheets, which complicates the logic.

Comment: I believe that jQuery.css() takes computer styles into account.

Comment: I tested your answer and it works in the cases I was envisioning, but the interesting side effect is that all elements covered get `outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;` as an inline style. I believe I'll end up going with the stylesheet and class option though (was trying to avoid it initially, but I see now that it is probably the best).

Comment: No worries, classes are probably the best way to go.

Comment: @dieuwe Do not forget that you can create stylesheets dynamically as well, which means you could create a function that creates a temporary CSS class and destroys it once styles can be removed.

Comment: @plalx That's a great option too. In my particular case I don't have control over the HTML/CSS, just the JS script that gets loaded remotely. I've opted to append a short `<style>` tag to `<head>` at the top of my script for now, but adding/removing it when needed might be a great idea. I only need the class to be present under certain circumstances and doesn't need to be "cluttering" the page unnecessarily.